# Visualforce page apex:actionfunction form validation

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

I have an action function that is being used to call a save method on controller which is reloading page.

When I call this save method from a command button, there is a validation on the form fields so that fields marked as required display a warning and the form is not submitted. But when I call save method from action function there is no validation and the form is submitted even when required fields are not populated.

Is there any way to make sure that the actionFunction also validates required form fields before submitting?

```
<apex:page controller="SoTestController">
    <apex:form>
        <input type="checkbox" required="true" style="margin-right: 10px;" />
        <span>Tick This</span>
        <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" styleclass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="SAVE"/>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{! save }" name="jsSave">
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <div onclick="jsSave()">
           CLICK TO SAVE
        </div> 
    </apex:form>
       
</apex:page>
```

```
public class SoTestController {
    public pageReference save() {
        System.debug('saved');
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you change the `<input ...>` to an `apex:inputCheckbox` ?

Comment: If I change it to an apex:inputCheckbox it doesn't validate it for either the actionfunction or the commandbutton - it just submits right away.

Comment: did you add the `required=` attribute on `apex:inputCheckbox` ?

Comment: Yes I did - required = "true"